# How can I find a file with the longest pathname on macOS?

Tags: macos, bash, find

I’m trying to debug an issue with my Backblaze backup tool, somewhere I have a file with a really long pathname that I need to locate. What terminal command could I use to find the file with the longest full path name or list something like the top 10 long name files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command should do the job:-

```
find /DirHead|while read -r f; do echo $(wc -c <<<$f): $f; done|sort -n|tail -n 1
```

Following Gordon Davisson's comment, there is a neater alternative:-

```
find /DirHead | awk '{print length($0), $0}' | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

You can set `/DirHead` to `/`, but this will be very slow, so if you have an idea where this long path may reside it will speed things up if you use it.

This will not follow symbolic links: if you want to do this you will need to add options to `find`.

For each file `wc -c` counts the number of bytes in the file name from standard input, and this count is output with the file name; the last line of a numeric sort will then be the longest, or `tail -n 10` will list the 10 longest.

I tested this on Ubuntu, not having easy access to OS/X.

Comment: You can speed it up by replacing the `while read` loop with `awk '{print length($0), $0}'`. BTW, I tested it (both the `while read` and `awk` variants) on macOS and it works there too.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Thanks, it's a lot neater.